# A Bayesian estimate for rank

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not sure how to put this succinctly but here is the problem.

Consider a random variable $X$ which can take a finite number of non-negative values.  It takes each value with the same probability.

Now consider a fixed value $y$ which is one of the values $X$ can take.  We would like to estimate what proportion of the values in the range of $X$ are bigger than $y$.

Our prior belief is that it is 50% of them.  After sampling $n$ times from $X$, how should one update this belief in a Bayesian framework?

---

The prior belief should be uniform in the range, not simply 50% .

Comment: So are you saying though we no X is discrete uniform over some non negative values, we don't actually know what those values are?

Comment: @user159813 Yes that is right.

Comment: Ok then this is pretty much the same question as the german tank problem(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem). Your question is not exactly the same but can be answered with the methods in this problem Im pretty sure

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer I only want the proportion, not the actual number. I am not expert enough to tell if your wiki link can be applied to my problem. Could you give some details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your prior belief is *just* 50%, then you will never come to any other conclusion. What you need to do is equally weight all possible fractions:

Let $p_0(f_y)\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ be your Bayesian prior density for the fraction of observations larger than a given $y$(i.e., $f_y$).

Now, lets get our $n$ observations of $X$, call this $S$. How do we modify our prior?

$p(f_y=z|S) \propto  p_0(z)P(S|f_y=z)=z^{\gamma}(1-z)^{\lambda}$ where $\gamma :=$ number of observations strictly greater than  $y$, and $\lambda :=$ number of observations less than or equal to $y$.

You simply normalize the above function to get your posterior density.

Unfortunately, this does not uniquely identify the bounds on the actual values of X.Y You need additional conditions to get a unique solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. My prior was incorrect as you pointed out. To compute $p_0(z)$ do we need to integrate over [0,1]?

Comment: @Lembik $p_0(z)$ is just a prior, so its defined. The unnormalized probability is easily found via the realtion in my post. The only integration required is to derive the normalization constant to change the $\propto$ to a $=$.